# Sharepoint 2013 "Everyone" user permission

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

I have Sharepoint enterprise server with list that have "Everyone" user grant as contributor

but, when I execute below code with authenticated user (let say, user Abc), for add item list row, the row never added to list

```
SPWeb web1 = SPContext.Current.Web;
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web1.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList roomList = web.Lists.TryGetList(LIST_NAME);
                if (roomList != null)
                {
                    SPListItem newItem = roomList.Items.Add();
                    PopulateListWithData(data, ref newItem);
                    newItem.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I add row to list with user Abc?

Answer (score 0):

try to add using following code

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web))
    {  
          SPList roomList = web.Lists.TryGetList(LIST_NAME);
                if (roomList != null)
                {
                    SPListItem newItem = roomList.AddItem();
                    PopulateListWithData(data, ref newItem);
                    newItem.Update();
                }
    }
 }
```

if you still have the same issue 
try to ensure the following

1. list you try to add to already exists in root web site
2. List name is types right because your code may be break after **TryGetList**

after that if still have the same issue you need to debug or check sharepoint logs to catch exception that happen